# Simple key remapping using IOKit with Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, hid, iokit

In macOS, the `IOKit` `HID` APIs can be used for key remapping. In the example below, <kbd>A</kbd> key is remapped to <kbd>B</kbd> key, and vice versa, using Objective-C.

Is it possible to do the same remapping programmatically with the latest Swift 5.5? If it can be done, **how does the example below look rewritten in Swift**?

Or is there a new, more modern API that can be used with Swift to accomplish the same task?

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h>
#import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDServiceClient.h>
#import <IOKit/hid/IOHIDUsageTables.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IOHIDEventSystemClientRef system;
    CFArrayRef services;
 
    uint64_t aKey = 0x700000004;
    uint64_t bKey = 0x700000005;
 
    NSArray *map = @[
                     @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(aKey),
                        @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(bKey)},
                     @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(bKey),
                        @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(aKey)},
                     ];
 
    system = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreateSimpleClient(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    services = IOHIDEventSystemClientCopyServices(system);
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(services); i++) {
        IOHIDServiceClientRef service = (IOHIDServiceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(services, i);
        if(IOHIDServiceClientConformsTo(service, kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard)) {
            IOHIDServiceClientSetProperty(service, CFSTR(kIOHIDUserKeyUsageMapKey), (CFArrayRef)map);
        }
    }
 
    CFRelease(services);
    CFRelease(system);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your cursed code in Swift 5.5 like this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
     remapKeys()
  }

  func remapKeys() {
    let aKey: UInt64 = 0x700000004
    let bKey: UInt64 = 0x700000005
    
    let map: [[String: UInt64]] = [
      [kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:aKey,
       kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:bKey],
      [kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:bKey,
       kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:aKey],
    ]
    
    let system = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreateSimpleClient(kCFAllocatorDefault)
    let services = IOHIDEventSystemClientCopyServices(system)
    
    for service in services as! [IOHIDServiceClient] {
      if((IOHIDServiceClientConformsTo(service, UInt32((kHIDPage_GenericDesktop)), UInt32(kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard))) != 0) {
        IOHIDServiceClientSetProperty(service, kIOHIDUserKeyUsageMapKey as CFString, map as CFArray)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

providing you create a bridging header containing these imports:

```
#import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h>
#import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDServiceClient.h>
#import <IOKit/hid/IOHIDUsageTables.h>
```

Comment: I wasn’t able to get it to work. I did setup the bridging header correctly but to no avail.

Comment: that's weird, it works for me and it's very, very annoying. what os are you trying it on? try my repo: https://github.com/rfistman/swift-key-remap

Comment: Not working since macOS 14.2. [Related post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/18g4vxn/cannot_remap_keys_on_macbook_pro_with_hidutils_in/) Do you have any idea? (I've tried execute my executable as `sudo`)

Comment: The article you linked says this has been fixed in 14.3 if you run with sudo

Comment: I've tried it. Not worked. (14.3 and 14.4)